# map on click fires when GeoJSON is clicked on leaflet 1.0

Tags: leaflet

In leaflet 1.0 beta2, when clicking on a GeoJSON with a click function assigned along with a map click function defined, they both fire instead of just one. This doesn't happen in the older versions of leaflet. See fiddle for examples.  Any workarounds for this?

Leaflet 7.7
http://jsfiddle.net/tator/5e209s9c/14/

Leaflet 1.0 beta2
http://jsfiddle.net/tator/em9cLfk4/4/

```
// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([41, -98], 5);

//when map is clicked run identify
map.on('click', identify);

// Identify function
function identify(e) {
    alert('click on the map');
};

//example geojson
var states = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Republican"},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-104.05, 48.99],
            [-97.22,  48.98],
            [-96.58,  45.94],
            [-104.03, 45.94],
            [-104.05, 48.99]
        ]]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Democrat"},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-109.05, 41.00],
            [-102.06, 40.99],
            [-102.03, 36.99],
            [-109.04, 36.99],
            [-109.05, 41.00]
        ]]
    }
}];

//style the polygon with clickedgeojson function
parpoly = L.geoJson(states, {
    style: {
    color: '#ff7800',
    weight: 1.5,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0
   },
   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: clickedgeojson
     });
    }
});

//clickedgeojson function
function clickedgeojson(e) {
    alert('click on json');
};

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);

//add the geojson to map
parpoly.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `L.DomEvent`'s `stopPropagation` method:

> Stop the given event from propagation to parent elements.

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#domevent-stoppropagation

```
//clickedgeojson function
function clickedgeojson(e) {
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
    alert('click on json');
};
```

Here's a working fork of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hakw66nj/

Or you can add the `click` event to the `nonBubblingEvents` array in your layer's options object. This goes currently undocumented so i can't link to any documentation just to the commit on Github:

> Add nonBubblingEvents option (fix #3604)

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/74018f284e8c58d022a9a127406867438aa2a4d0

```
new L.GeoJSON(collection, {
    nonBubblingEvents: ['click']
})
```

Here's a fork of your Fiddle using this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hdd8rgkm/

Comment: I see. I thought it was a bug in the beta version of leaflet 1.0 ... however Ivan Sanchez informed me, "events from layers bubble up to the map"(https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4258).

Comment: Yes, i was aware of that :) It was mentioned in the CHANGELOG.md: "Improved DOM event bubbling mechanism for layers (by @yohanboniface). Leaflet/Leaflet#3307 #3450 #3307" Looking that up, i saw i forgot another option you have for stopping the eventbubbling, i'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

iH8 gave you a good answer if you want to stop propagation altogether.  However if you still want the map function to fire you can just add in a variable check.  Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzlydev/em9cLfk4/5/).

```
var idGeo = 0;

// Identify function
function identify(e) {
    if(idGeo ==1){
    idGeo = 0;
  }else{
    alert('click on the map');
    idGeo = 0;
  }
};

//clickedgeojson function
function clickedgeojson(e) {
    idGeo = 1;
    alert('click on json');
};
```

Comment: I see how this could be useful. If you only wanted to do a part of the map click function if the geojson was clicked. This works because the geoJSON click function is fired before the map click.